# SQL Server : Subquery returned more than 1 value when selecting data with subquery

Tags: sql-server, sql-like

I'm trying to select all the `tgl_awal` data from `debitur` plus all of the data of `ask`. So in other words, I show all of the data of `ask` plus the `tgl_awal` and `tgl_akhir` from `debitur`. Using below query results showing the values of added columns from `debitur` (not null)

```
SELECT ask.*, d.tgl_awal, d.tgl_akhir
FROM 
temp_r.['OS ASKRED OKT 18$'] ask
inner JOIN dbo.customer c ON ask.id_customer = c.id_customer
inner join dbo.debitur d on c.id_customer = d.id_customer
```

But because above query returns different number of rows than the original number of data (without joining it) so I changed the form of query into

```
SELECT ask.*
,(select debitur.tgl_awal from debitur where debitur.id_customer = c.id_customer ) as tgl_awal
,(select debitur.tgl_akhir from debitur where debitur.id_customer = c.id_customer ) as tgl_akhir
FROM 
temp_r.['OS ASKRED OKT 18$'] ask
inner JOIN dbo.customer c ON ask.id_customer = c.id_customer
```

But then it returns `Subquery returned more than 1 value.` how am I supposed to query this? I need to join them without adding more rows than the original rows and without having all nulls in the joined columns

Comment: There are multiple rows in `debitur` for some `id_customer`. You need to explain how you want to handle this. Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

The Error ("Subquery returned more than 1 value") is due to the **SUB- Queries** in the Select Statement.

I think, The Table(debitur) which has multiple entries against the single Customer_ID Column in the "dbo.customer" table.

This will leads to the above Error.

But it can be rectified by using the Below options:

By TOP:

```
SELECT ask.*
,(select TOP 1  debitur.tgl_awal from debitur where debitur.id_customer = c.id_customer ) as tgl_awal
,(select  TOP 1  debitur.tgl_akhir from debitur where debitur.id_customer = c.id_customer ) as tgl_akhir
FROM 
temp_r.['OS ASKRED OKT 18$'] ask
inner JOIN dbo.customer c ON ask.id_customer = c.id_customer
```

By Join :

```
SELECT ask.*
,(debitur.tgl_awal) as tgl_awal
,(debitur.tgl_akhir  ) as tgl_akhir
FROM 
temp_r.['OS ASKRED OKT 18$'] ask
inner JOIN dbo.customer c ON ask.id_customer = c.id_customer
INNER JOIN debitur ON debitur.id_customer = c.id_customer
```

By Sub Query:

```
SELECT ask.*
,S.debitur.tgl_awal as tgl_awal
,S.debitur.tgl_akhir as tgl_akhir
 FROM 
 temp_r.['OS ASKRED OKT 18$'] ask
 inner JOIN dbo.customer c ON ask.id_customer = c.id_customer
 INNER JOIN( select debitur.tgl_awal, debitur.tgl_akhir,id_customer from debitur ) S ON S.id_customer = c.id_customer
```

Comment: I advise against the `TOP 1` solution here; there is no `ORDER BY` meaning that *any* arbitrary row could be returned; meaning the result would be inconsistent and could be different *every* time the query is run.